# What are the elements of a state called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example if I have a state

```js
state = {
    bob: true,
    mob: {
        sob: true
    }
}
```

What are names you could call `bob`, `mob` and `sob`? Elements? Fields? Properties? And how do you describe the relationship between `sob` and `mob`? Is `mob` `sob`'s parent? Is `mob` a Javascript object?

Comment: state is just a regular ol' _object_ so you would stay consistent with referring to it's properties as, properties ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bob`, `mob`, and `sob` are *properties*. The first two are properties of the state object itself, the last is a property of the object `mob` refers to. Loosely speaking, `sob`'s *parent* is `mob`. Loosely. :-)

It's also not uncommon to hear them called *fields*, but that's not generally what they're called in the JavaScript community.

Answer (score 0):

`bob`, `mod` & `sob` as also mentioned by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) are called [`properties`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp).

- In an object, you can free call them anything you want, but usually,
  they are called `Children` or `Nodes`.
- `sob` in your case is `mob`'s child node.
- `mob` is an object.

To access them you can do like so:

---

```js
state = {
  bob: true,
  mob: {
    sob: true
  }
}

console.log("State: " + state);
console.log("State.bob: " + state.bob);
console.log("State.mob: " + state.mob);
console.log("State.mob.sob: " + state.mob.sob);
```